# AddThis module cannot be installed in Joomla 1.5.26

Tags: joomla1.5, addthis

I have downloaded AddThis module for Joomla 1.5 but when I tried to install it, an error is shown telling that installation XML cannot be found.

Does anybody know how to install it correctly?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have "XML cannot be found", the problem is: your Module isn't compatible with your Joomla version.

Hope it's helpful for you.